# Error when generating large numbers with a condition

Tags: java

I need to generate players(any number) of large numbers with the condition that all of them will be less than P. But for some reason, when generating the resulting array, it either goes beyond the players range or generates numbers greater than P. How to generate it correctly?

```
ArrayList<BigInteger> C = new ArrayList<>(players);

for(int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
    do {
        C.add(i, new BigInteger(64, random));
    } while (C.get(i).compareTo(P) > 0);
}
```

Comment: why do you have a while loop? In this while loop nothing is changing, so `C.get(i).compareTo(P) > 0` will also never change

Comment: Understood. I need a loop so that it generates a number until the condition C < P is met. Apparently I didn’t write the condition correctly, how it will be right

Comment: the reason for your error is you are adding the integer into the C regardless whether the generated number is larger than P. meaning your list will grow larger than your ```players```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for your error is you are adding the integer into the C regardless whether the generated number is larger than P. meaning your list will grow larger than your players

also please follow the naming convention and use camel case for your variable names

do sth like this instead

```
        ArrayList<BigInteger> integerList = new ArrayList<>(players);
        while (integerList.size()<players-1){
            BigInteger randomInt = new BigInteger(64, random);
            if(randomInt.compareTo(p) > 0){
                integerList.add(randomInt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: my bad fixed it